# Titanium web app OPTIONS instead of GET

Tags: web, titanium, http-options-method

I'm trying to compile a Titanium app for Web.
When I try to contact the server via http request in the browser console I see a OPTIONS method
instead of a GET method:

```
var request = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
request.open('GET', url);

request.onload = function() {
    Ti.API.debug('CALLBACK OK');
};
request.onerror = function(e) {
    Ti.API.debug('CALLBACK ERROR' + e.error);   
};
request.send(args);
```

The request reach the server but e.error said "Can't reach host".
I've tryed to do a OPTIONS request before this request fallowing:
http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
and setting in the first response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: myserverurl
Access-Control-Max-Age: 2520
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE, GET, POST, XMODIFY
```

But I get the same response and the code executed is the onerror function...

Pleas help me I'm wasting ours...

Answer (score 2):

Ok,
It's obviously a XSS problem
a workaround is to disabled browser security.
e.g. in Chromium:

```
# chromium --disable-web-security
```

Comment: For mac users: `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security`. Make sure chrome is not open though.